# I am trying to check that user input is 1 of 4 accepted file types in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting and writing code in general. I am writing a script that should accept 1 of 4 different file types. There is an if elif condition to check if the file exist and if the file is the correct file type. It makes it through this check, but if I give it the correct file type it thinks I gave it the wrong type and echos my error message.

I have tried  running it on all file types and get the same error message every time. When I wrote a similar bit of code but checked for only one file type, I did not have this issue. I believe I am doing something incorrect with || possibly.

```
# Check if there is a valid file
if [[ ! -f $FILE_INPUT ]]; then
  echo ""
  echo "  FILE ERROR:   "$FILE_INPUT" does not exist!"
  echo ""
  echo ""
  echo "  Script must now terminate..."
  echo ""
  exit $EXIT_ERROR_FILE
elif [[ $FILE_INPUT != *.abc ]] || [[ $FILE_INPUT != *.def ]] || [[ $FILE_INPUT != *.ghi ]] || [[ $FILE_INPUT != *.jkl ]]; then
  echo ""
  echo "FILE ERROR:  "$FILE_INPUT" is not an accepted file type"
  echo ""
  echo ""
  echo "  Script must now terminate..."
  echo ""
  exit $EXIT_ERROR_FILE
fi
```

Comment: Bonus, don't use lots of echos for breaklines. Try something like `echo -e "\n\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong; you want `&&`, not `||`.

e.g. right now, if you pass `123.abc` it will still hit the `*.def` case and flag an error.

Comment: Oh man. That is embarrassing. I suppose I was reading it as: If file does not meet this condition OR this condition OR this condition etc... Thanks for the help!

Comment: This answer has spotted the bug correctly. However, also have a look at the [`case` statement](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) in `bash`. This requirement is a typical use case for the `case ... esac`.

Comment: `echo "FILE ERROR:  "$FILE_INPUT" is not an accepted file type"` also this doesn't need a break in your string, you can just keep the initial set of quotes!